# Semantic HTML use of QR codes

Tags: html, qr-code, semantic-markup

How can I make my HTML markup more semantic when using a QR code?

The following code doesn't look all that semantic. The only thing conveyed is that it is an image.

```html
<img src="/generate_qr_code?value=https://example.com/" />
```

Is there any way I can improve the semantics?

Maybe wrap it in an anchor? (if the QR code is a URL)

```html
<a href="https://example.com/"><img src="/generate_qr_code?value=https://example.com/" /></a>
```

Should I have any `alt` or `title` attribute on the `img` element? What should be in those attributes?

```html
<img src="/generate_qr_code?value=https://example.com/" title="QR code" alt="https://example.com/" />
```

Would that be correct and proper usage of the `alt` and `title` attributes?

Is there any [ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) attributes or `role` attribute that I can use in this context?

Comment: I would imagine this depends a bit on what the QR code is used for, do you have any specific purpose in mind, or just a generic best practice when including one?

Comment: There's some good information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59074149/14956277) by [Graham Ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2702894/graham-ritchie).

Comment: And I found this at Google who don't seem to say too much about the HTML semantics. https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes